# How to filter all query results in laravel 4.2 app by year

Tags: php, filter, laravel-4, model

I want to add a filter for all application queries to get the result by a specific year.

I am putting the current year into the session as shown below:

```
public function postLogin()
{
    Session::put('currentYear', date("Y"));
}
```

I have many controllers in my application. I want any model's query result to filter by session year =>  Session::get('currentYear')

I have a lot of models; for example I have one route to view all users, teachers and students.

```
public function getList()
{
    $data['students'] = User::where('group_id', '=', 4)->get();

    return View::make('students.list', $data);
}
```

Can I put `__construct` in BaseController to filter all app queries by `Session::get('currentYear')`?

Comment: Take a look to global scope https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#global-scopes

Comment: Why not just add the where clause to your specific functions? Adding a global filter might affect other queries as well.

Answer (score 3):

I would create a repository class with a method that provides the desired base query, such as
`function getUserBaseQuery() {
  return User::where('year', '=', Session::get('currentYear'));
}`

Obviously make sure that `currentYear` is set - and return this without running `get()` just yet.

Then get this base query whenever you make a query, add more operations (limit, order, whatever) and run `get()`.

This way you can access with your filter without doing some global potential damage and stay aware what filters are run by choosing that base query.

Does that make sense to you?

Comment: It looks like I will make same filter for each model in the application.
Before I saw application with session year select menu and when you login to this app you can change the year then you will retrieve only the selected year records for all views and models . I think it will be better to make global filter for all models in the application. any idea about that solution ?

Comment: You could add a parameter to the method in which you hand over the model class name, such as "User". Then use $model::where(…) to apply your general filters.